# Xcode UITableView Placement and Cell Separators

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, cell

I am having a problem where my UITableView is not extending all the way to the bottom of the page even though I have it set up so that I believe it should.

[Table doesn't extend to bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUnEd.png)

Also, the cell separators do not seem to show up unless I scroll the table.

[Cell separators show up only on scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWtn3.png)

Comment: Check the warning symbols in Xcode. They'll probably be telling you your auto layout constraints aren't set up correctly. Satisfy them, and you should get what you want.

Comment: @Mark That did fix the placement issue, thanks! I still have the issue with the cell separators not appearing though.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the property automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets to NO like this.

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

or

```
self.navigationController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

EDIT:

from your screenshots its seems to be constraint problem. Try setting constraints left, right, top, bottom and try again. You see the yellow line coming and a warning regarding the constraint problem. When it goes your  table view will work fine.

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix the problem. :(

Comment: I have fixed the constraint problems and everything in that ViewController is as it should be now in terms of layout. However, I am still getting this problem where the separator lines between cells aren't showing up. Any more thoughts? I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

In your `viewDidLoad` method, add this:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeBottom
```

Answer (score 0):

For the separator issue try setting the separator style `[[self tableView] setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];` or `self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine`